# Performing select count across two tables sql

Tags: sql, drupal, inner-join

I have a table relationship which links one person to many relatives. so the tables are 1. Client. 2. Client_relative.  I want to display all the rows of the Persons table, while displaying a count of how many relatives each person has. I have this query:

`SELECT c.clientid, c.fname, c.lname, count(cr.relativeid) as relativecount FROM {client} AS c INNER JOIN {client_relative} cr on c.clientid = cr.clientid`

This isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select c.*, cc.relativecount
from client c
inner join (
    select clientid, count(*) as relativecount  
    from client_relative
    group by clientid 
) cc on c.clientid = cc.clientid
```

Comment: Wait a minute... I swear I saw your post doing the join before the group by. But there's no edit history... strange.

Comment: Hi Red, actually, I notice that if the client doesn't have a relative, this query doesn't output the client. It just ignores those that don't have relatives. Any ideas? Thanks-

Comment: OK, I replaced the INNER JOIN with a LEFT JOIN and this solved the issue.

Comment: @berto, yes, that is the way to handle that. You can change `cc.relativecount` to `ISNULL(cc.relativecount, 0)` to get slightly nicer output in your `SELECT` clause.